# "Could not find valid value for id" when processing contribution batch

Tags: civicontribute, batches

When pushing the button "Validate & process batch" after entering contributions, the screen seems to refresh... but nothing is processed: no contribution is added, no confirmation email is sent.

Drupal watchlog shows this backtrace:

```
$backTrace = 
#0 .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(378): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Request.php(120): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Could not find valid value for id")
#2 .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Batch/Form/Entry.php(89): CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve("id", "Positive", Object(CRM_Batch_Form_Entry), TRUE)
#3 .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(543): CRM_Batch_Form_Entry->preProcess()
#4 .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(92): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#5 .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Batch_Form_Entry), "display")
#6 .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Batch_Form_Entry), "display")
#7 .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#8 .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(113): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#9 .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(282): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Batch_Form_Entry", NULL, (Array:0))
#10 .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:12))
#11 .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#12 .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(448): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#13 .../includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("batch", "entry")
#14 .../index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#15 {main}
```

Where to find (or add) this id value? Or is it another issue?

CiviCRM 4.7.29 Drupal 7.56

Answer (score 0):

It is very strange that it does not find and id here. The error occurs in the php file CRM/Batch/Form/Entry.

Can you try this issue on one of the demo sites (https://civicrm.org/demo) so you can check if this is a core bug or a problem in your installation?

Comment: On the demo site, the batch was executed succesfully: the contribution was added.
Meanwhile, i made an update to Civi 4.7.30, with the same non result. But this time even without an error, not in the Drupal watchdog log, not in the Civi ConfigAndLog.

Comment: If the demo processes correctly it looks like an issue on your installation. That would require some debugging to find out what the problem is, might be some data issue? Afraid that is almost impossible from a distance :-)

Comment: MarkDQ, do your contributions have custom fields assigned to them? Have you tried disabling any extensions which might interject/play with contributions somehow and see if it works?